# Random numbers simulating stock market returns

Tags: python, numpy, random

Let me say right from the beginning that I know just a little bit about statistics, but not enough to figure out this problem.

I'm trying to create a list of n random floating point numbers to simulate annual stock market returns. The numbers should range from -30.0 to +30.0 with an average of 7.0. The numbers should be distributed mostly around the average, but they should be well distributed. Basically, it should be a flattened bell curve, so there should be a good chance of having some negative numbers as well as some numbers closer to the upper limit.

I know numpy has functions to create random numbers that are distributed in different ways, but not sure how to specify these parameters.

Comment: There are any number of distributions that have those properties. If you just want to come up with anything that meets the criteria, then you don't have a programming question, you have a math question. If you specifically want it to be realistic based on the historical performance of the stock market, then you also have a quantitative finance question, but you still don't have a programming question.

Comment: After that, if you come up with a distribution that is well known, or easy to express in terms of well-known functions, and need help implementing it - then you *might* have a question for Stack Overflow, but only after you've tried checking the NumPy documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is there anything you have tried that didn't produce the expected distribution? How would you grade an answer, what hard criteria apply?

Comment: I've more-or-less settled on using np.random.normal(7.0, 10.0, n) to get a random set of numbers. The number of samples I'm generating is small (no more than 50) so it gives me a list that varies quite a bit. I'm trying to come up with random annual returns to see if an account can stay positive years in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sample from a nomal distribution that has your chosen mean (mu) and a large standard deviation (sigma) to flatten it.

Here's some code to get you started

```
import numpy as np
mu, sigma, n = 7.0, 3.0, 1000 # mean and standard deviation
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n)
```

Note that the larger sigma is, the further your samples will be from the mean and could exceed your +-30 limits. So choose a suitable sigma (like three sigmas from your mean to the extreme), or you'll have to clip your numbers to the limit.

Also note that stock market returns aren't necessarily normally distributed.